# DOCTYPE necessary for HTML includes?

Tags: html, coding-style

I'm working on a new web application that has a common footer included on all pages. What I'm wondering is if it is necessary or if there is any benefit at all to having the footer file include HTML, HEAD and BODY tags as shown below?

Is this good or bad practice?  To me it seems to just bloat the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        ... common js and css files
    </head>
    <body>
        ... html for the current page

        <!-- Footer -->
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                ... legal information
            </body>
        </html>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What?!? Why would one ever do that?

Comment: @delnan one reason I do see for doing it is if (for whatever reason) you want to include some script in the HEAD tags of the included file.

Comment: ... as opposed to properly communicating that so it turns up in the "right" (first) `<head>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there should only be one html and body tag in a html document unless it's contained within another iframe.

A standard compliant html document would contain the following structure:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ... common js and css files
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>   
        ... html for the current page
        </div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div>
                ... legal information
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that markup is wrong, in the footer you should only include the code relevant to the footer.

Answer (score 0):

No, your common include should just contain the HTML for that specific piece of the page. The master template should include tags such as html, head, body.